# JUnit: testing an object is not in a list

Tags: java, list, junit

In JUnit tests, I need to test that a given object (not the reference, but the attributes of the object) is not in a list. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you specify an example please?

Comment: *not the reference, but the attributes*???? Whatever could that mean???

Comment: @Sean Means does not want to test for `x == y` (reference) equality, which is what you get unless you override Object.equals.

Comment: Could you explain what _not the reference, but the attributes of the object_ means to you? If you refer to the object inside the list, some answers might help you (overriding equals for example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using a current version of JUnit, the best way to do it would be to write your own Matcher for a list of objects of your type.

Create a class extending `org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher` and implement the methods given.
Add a static constructor method for your class, so you can easily call it in your `assertThat` statement and hand over a example of the object that should not be contained.
In the `matchesSafely()` method, assure that your list contains no object that matches the attributes of your sample.

As an alternative, implement `equals` on your object, create a sample and then do
`assertThat(yourList,not(hasItem(yourSample)));`, where `not` is a static import from `CoreMatchers`, and `hasItem` is a static import from `JUnitMatchers`.

Of course, once you implement `equals` you can simple `assertFalse(yourList.contains(yourSample));`

Comment: I would still recommend using the assertThat approach even with equals because of better error message when it fails.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question properly:

```
Object o =....; //some object
assertFalse(list.contains(o));
```

This can work if the object `equals()` method has been properly implemented.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: he wants to know if an object is in a list and not if an object is a list.

Comment: He said it needed to be tested for membership in a list, not if it's a list.

Comment: Should be assertFalse - he said *not* in a list.

Answer (score 2):

I assume doing a simple contains() is not a deep enough check? If you've overriden your object's equals() method already then list.contains( o ) would work.

Answer (score 0):

If the Objects you store in the List implement `equals` to match these attributes, then [list.contains(o)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) or [list.indexOf(o)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) will give you the answer.

If your objects do not implement [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), then these methods will answer based on reference equality (not what you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testContains() {
    String demoObject = "Testing!";
    //myList isa List<String>
    assertFalse("Object was in collection", myList.contains(demoObject));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to assert that a property of some objects in a list isn't equals at something....
if you can user the commons collection ( http://commons.apache.org/collections/ ) you can use the interface **org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate** to search in a list (using the method *org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.find(List, Predicate)*

you can make somenthing like

```
Predicate p = new Predicate(){
    /*
     * Test if the object has the value that you don't want
     */
    public boolean evaluate(java.lang.Object object){
         YourObject yo = (YourObject) object;
         return yo.getProperty().equals(theValue);
    }
}
//if is return null means that nothing was found
assertNull(CollectionUtils.find(yourList, p));
```